# How to load a picture through Base64 instead of URL?

Tags: javascript

The code lets me load an image from normal URL,

But I want load the image from base64 url: data:image/png;base64

```
<br/><button onClick="selectRandImage()">Pick Random Image</button><input id="imgUrl" style="width:45%" value=""><button onclick="updateImageUrl()">draw</button>


var width, height
var step = 0;
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
var canvasColor = document.createElement('canvas')
var ctxColor = canvasColor.getContext('2d')
var canvasThreshold = document.createElement('canvas')
var ctxThreshold = canvasThreshold.getContext('2d')
var bg = [128, 128, 128]
var img, n


document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(canvasColor)
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(canvasThreshold)
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(canvas)

ctrl = {
threshold: 0.5,
run: function () {
setup()
}
}

var gui = new dat.GUI();
gui.add(ctrl, 'threshold', 0, 1);
gui.add(ctrl, 'run');

var imgUrl = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/06/19/23/bull-1575005__340.jpg'
loadImage(imgUrl)
var images = [
'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/13/10/25/hummingbird-2139279__340.jpg',

'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/12/11/51/forest-1818690__340.jpg'
]
function selectRandImage() {
document.getElementById('imgUrl').value = images[Math.round((images.length - 1) * Math.random())]
}

selectRandImage()
updateImageUrl()

function updateImageUrl() {
loadImage(document.getElementById('imgUrl').value)
}
function loadImage (imgUrl) {
var tempimg = new Image()
tempimg.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"
tempimg.onload = function() {
img = tempimg
setup()
}
tempimg.src = 'https://crossorigin.me/' + imgUrl
}

function setup() {
if (img === undefined) {
return
}

var scale = 1

// setup actual drawing canvas
canvasThreshold.width = canvasColor.width = canvas.width = width = img.width * scale //window.innerWidth
canvasThreshold.height = canvasColor.height = canvas.height = height =  img.height * scale //window.innerHeigh

// cet ref for color
ctxColor.scale(scale, scale)
ctxColor.drawImage(img, 0, 0)

imageThreshold(canvasColor, ctxThreshold)
}

function imageThreshold(srcCanvas, destContext) {
destContext.drawImage(srcCanvas, 0, 0);
var imgData = destContext.getImageData(0, 0, srcCanvas.width, srcCanvas.height)
var d = imgData.data;

var red, green, blue, i
for (i = 0; i < d.length; i += 4) {
red = d[i] / 265;
green = d[i+1] / 265;
blue = d[i+2] / 265;
if (red < ctrl.threshold || green < ctrl.threshold || blue < ctrl.threshold)     {
d[i + 0] = 255
d[i + 1] = 255
d[i + 2] = 255
} else {
d[i + 0] = 0
d[i + 1] = 0
d[i + 2] = 0
}
```

i need help to change the code please,
so it will let me put base64 url.

codepen:

codepen.io/scorch/pen/zZJmmb

base64 image for test:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

Comment: I guess you haven't tried much research since many solutions appear on google when searching "javascript base64 encode image"  Maybe this will help. If you don't know how to impliment this then I suggest you find a tutorial or hire a developer https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [post base64 encode image to server using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573046/post-base64-encode-image-to-server-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the base64 string directly from the `canvas` you are drawing the image on to:

```
var base64 = srcCanvas.toDataURL();
```

You can do the conversion inside of your `imageThreshold` function:

```
function imageThreshold(srcCanvas, destContext) {
    destContext.drawImage(srcCanvas, 0, 0);
    var base64 = srcCanvas.toDataURL();
    //....
}
```

To do the reverse, you can set your image.src to the base64 and then draw your image object onto your canvas using your context:

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
};
image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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";
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">

var srcCanvas = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = srcCanvas.getContext("2d");

var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    };
    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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";



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Someone edited the post title without permission. The question was different. How can I load the image from a base64 address? I already have an address for my picture. I edited the post and added a image link + codepen